Dynamically Switching a Range in a SUMIF()
I have a formula in excel that looks like this:
=SUMIFS(SILOADRESERVED,
    SIPDU,
    B8&"*",
    SIPHASE, "A",
    SITYPE, "<>RMT"
)

The challenge is that SIPDU range changes for different phases of the project, so I'd like to replace it with a different range depending on the outcome of a conditional, like below. If the phase we're interested in at AJ4 is less than the changeover phase for this element, the SUMIF search should be performed on the old range SIPDU, but if the phase has already happened, the SUMIF search should be performed on the new range, SI_NEW_PDU. These named ranges are adjacent columns of equal length.
=SUMIFS(SILOADRESERVED,
    IF($AJ$4<MD_Main_Changeover_Phase, SIPDU, SI_NEW_PDU),
    B8&"*",
    SIPHASE, "A",
    SITYPE, "<>RMT"
)

However, I'm receiving a SPILL error, and I'm not sure how to proceed. I'm using Office 365.
Some other approaches I tried that did not work:
=SUMIFS(SILOADRESERVED, INDEX((SIPDU, SI_NEW_PDU), MATCH($AJ$4<MD_Main_Changeover_Phase, {TRUE, FALSE}, 0)), B8&"*", SIPHASE, "A", SITYPE, "<>RMT")
=SUMIFS(SILOADRESERVED, CHOOSE(($AJ$4<MD_Main_Changeover_Phase)+1, SIPDU, SI_NEW_PDU), B8&"*", SIPHASE, "A", SITYPE, "<>RMT") 
I'm thinking the problem is that SUMIFS iterates over every row, but the $AJ$4<MD_Main_Changeover_Phase is nested inside the IF, so the MD_Main_Changeover_Phase isn't getting iterated over at the same time. I'm not sure how to get around this though.
I'm afraid to use helper columns, since this same problem occurs for eight different named ranges in my project, not just SIPDU. Each row in my data set represents an electrical load, with two sources, and the sources are stored across four columns (like an address). We are doing a phased project where we transition the loads to two new sources, but not necessarily during the same phase. So we are trying to track the loads during this transition. Four named ranges will be adjusted based on one phase range; the other four will be controlled based on a second phase range.
Edit: Here's a simpler example of what I'm trying to achieve with the results I need on the right. You can manually adjust the Current Phase to update the SUMIFS below.

Here's the same data in a copyable CSV format for others to use:



Equipment ID
Load
Old PDU
New PDU
Phase that we switch device over




1
5
A
D
1


2
5
A
E
1


3
10
B
F
2


4
10
B
F
3


5
20
C
H
4






Current Phase
2




Load on PDU A
0


Load on PDU B
10


Load on PDU C
20


Load on PDU D
5


Load on PDU E
5


Load on PDU F
10




is MD_Main_Changeover_Phase one cell or a range?

@ScottCraner, it is also a range, since each electrical row has a source that is going to change during a different phase.

Please post some sample copiable data so that one can copy the same and produce a solution for you. Also try to show your expected output. A solution will help you to point out what you need to do not necessary it has to be exact but it will help understanding what needs to be done in order to get the desired output. Hope it helps you to understand the relevance!

How do you get the last one as 0 shouldnt that be 10?

@MayukhBhattacharya It should, that was a typo, sorry!

try : =SUM((IF(H$1<E$2:E$6,C$2:C$6,D$2:D$6)=TEXTAFTER(G2," ",-1))*B$2:B$6)

Here is one way of solving the query:


=MAP(G2:G7, LAMBDA(α, 
 SUM((IF(H$1<E2:E6,C2:C6,D2:D6)=
 TEXTAFTER(α," ",-1))*B2:B6)))



Can you modify this to include additional criteria? Say, if column F had colors in it, and then we just wanted to look at the loads on PDUs A through F where the color is blue? And does it work with named ranges?

@mybluesock yes should work. also it not very big deal, just add the cell reference for color and range to compare. It will be something like this: =MAP(G2:G7, LAMBDA(α, SUM((IF(H$1<E2:E6,C2:C6,D2:D6)=TEXTAFTER(α," ",-1))*(F2:F6="blue")*B2:B6)))

I was able to get it to work using 'code' =MAP(G2:G8, LAMBDA(α, SUM((IF(H$1<E2:E6,C2:C6,D2:D6)= TEXTAFTER(α," ",-1))B2:B6(F2:F6="Blue")))) 'code', but I wasn't able to get it to work in my original spreadsheet. I'll experiment with it further next week. Thanks for the help!

@mybluesock can you post your excel(using onedrive link or googlesheets), which is not allowed(dont know there is no hard and fast rule, but we dont say due to opening of foreign links), however still i will try to look into it, if you wish! Ah one more thing just used named ranges and it worked as well: =MAP(G2:G7, LAMBDA(α, SUM((IF(H$1<SWITCH_OVER,Old_PDU,New_PDU)=TEXTAFTER(α," ",-1))*(F2:F6="blue")*Load)))

I just tested that out myself and thankfully it does. I'm afraid I'm not able to share the data since it's proprietary, but I imagine I'm just making a simple error. I'll come back if I'm still have problems next week though! Thanks again!

@mybluesock Thank you very much for sharing the feedback, glad to know it worked, also one request when posting query using this Markdown Table Generator its easy to use, just copy the data from your excel and paste in the said web, generate and copy paste here. simple

Will do, thanks! Also, I discovered the VALUE error I was experiencing was caused by my named ranges including the header row, so it's an easy fix!

There's an additional complication. This works: =SUM(LOAD * (PDU = "1A04")), but this does not: =SUM(LOAD * (PDU = "1A*")).

@mybluesock now that wont work. You will XMATCH() or MATCH() or SEARCH() + ISNUMBER() function. -> =SUM(LOAD*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("1A",PDU))) or =SUM(LOAD*(ISNUMBER(XMATCH("*1A*",PDU,2))))

I think I found a similar approach with this formula: =SUMPRODUCT(SILOADRESERVED, --(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B8&"*", IF($AJ$4<MD_Main_Changeover_Phase,SIPDU,SI_NEW_PDU)))),--(SIPHASE="A"),--(SITYPE<>"RMT")) However, the added complexity is going to appear across hundreds of formulas in some analysis spreadsheets, so I think in the end I'm going to lean on some helper columns in my original table, which will do something like this: =IF(OR(ISBLANK([@[Main Changeover Phase]]), ISBLANK([@[New PDU]])), [@PDU], IF(DPHASE<[@[Main Changeover Phase]],[@PDU],[@[New PDU]]))

@mybluesock do you have a sample data, and can you share me an excel link. I can take a look you dont need helper columns.
